# Force https on Azure Websites - web.config - Laravel 4

Tags: azure, iis, ssl, laravel-4

I'm trying to force https for all traffic.

I've tried numerous web.config rules found across the internet and microsofts own site, but none seem to redirect to https as they should.

I don't know if something has changed that has made all of these rules invalid, but regardless it is not working.

Here is what I've checked so far:

```
 <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
       <conditions>
          <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true"/>
       </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
```

```
 <rule name="Redirect to https">
  <match url="(.*)"/>
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

---

```
      <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

from:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-configure-ssl-certificate/

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could do it on the DNS side. One option would be setting up a page rule on cloud flare.

Answer (score 2):

Ok - Just wasted 2 hours on this but the answer was very subtle.

I am running laravel4 on azure websites, to get this to work it required two web.config files: One in the "site/wwwroot/public" folder and one in the "site/wwwroot".

My problem was that I forgot about this and was only modifying the one in the public folder.

The solution is to add the rule to the web.config file in site/wwwroot and  not in site/wwwroot/public.

I haven't tested all the rules i mentioned earlier but went with the one suggested by microsoft and it worked.

Good Luck.

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```